# Suddenly Oracle is throwing ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a query that is prefectly running fine for months, but suddenly, i am facing column ambiqious defiened error

```
INSERT INTO test.test_log
(org_id,
 comany,
 file_id,
 data_dt,
 file_date,
 stat_cd,
 cre_by_nm,
 cre_ts)
SELECT 900,
       'CVS',
       1074,
       To_date('2020-11-11', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
       To_date('2020-11-11', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
       'pending',
       'Process',
       To_timestamp_tz('2020-11-12 06:35:10.0 -00:00',
                       'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM')
FROM   dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 850,
       'WAl',
       1185,
       To_date('2020-11-11', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
       To_date('2020-11-09', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
       'pending',
       'Process',
       To_timestamp_tz('2020-11-12 06:35:10.0 -00:00',
                       'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM')
FROM   dual
```

I have a solution for this issue, in select statement we need to specify the column name also. But i am not sure why all of sudden this is coming up.

Error Information

```
Failed to insert the records
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and the select looks fine.  Please include the definition for your table.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=411f813826453f2af8925893c809f8c7) Cannot replicate this either.

Comment: Are you sure this is the statement that is raising the error? If it is, make sure you check the full error message, one possible explanation is a trigger being fired that contains the bug, the full error message should make this obvious.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ,MTO, Andrew Sayer. It ran fine for couple of months suddenly caused issue. I need to check with DBA regarding upgrade process

Comment: Can we see DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL for test_log and also 'select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'test_log', and also, can you reproduce the error in SQLPlus, SQLcl or SQL Developer?